# Faster time complexity data structure

Tags: performance, data-structures, time-complexity

What is the faster data structure in time complexity? and why ?
I need to make application thats works with huge amount of data.
my aplication is a hotel booking that will make in list a big hotels list (about 20000) to every country.
then I should work with this list (sort, search, traverse ...)
the list item contains th hotel name, stars number, ranking, last reservation, photo and the price
some research shows that hashtable is the faster structure, it takes O(1) for all operations (add, remove and find).
why I dont find information about JSON? can I classify a JSON object as listArray, hashMap or what??
and what will be faster ? saving my data (inserver side) in sql database ? XML ? or JSON ?

Comment: Every single well-known data structure I can think of will outperform plenty of others on some specific operation, making it a good choice for certain applications. There is no [silver bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_bullet#Idiomatic_usage). You need to tell us specifically which operations you wish to efficiently support, what your performance requirements are and say a bit more about your data beyond that there is a 'huge amount' of it (tell us more specifically how much there is and what it will look like).

Comment: i edited my question with more details :)

Comment: Will you be inserting and deleting a lot of times? What is the operation you will be performing more often?

Comment: after getting a hotels list, I should sort by price then display. So the most operation is traversing and sorting.

Comment: On which parameters to do want to sort / search? In which order do you want to traverse? If it varies a lot, the answer will likely just be "Use a database", as the data structure option is a somewhat complicated bunch of maps to essentially simulate a database (either abstractly, which is probably easier, or for all possible combinations of fields you want to query), that really shouldn't be done, unless it's just to learn. Can you say **exactly** which operations you want to support (efficiently) (you have a "..." there), as this is important to picking the structure, and how efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "faster" data structure, or we would all be using it and forget about everything else. Different data structures exist for different purposes; choosing one is often a matter of thinking about the most common operations. For example, an array is good for random access, but can be a terrible choice if you intend to insert or delete a lot of data in between elements. Lists, on the other hand, provide efficient insertion and deletion time, but lack efficient random access - it's all about tradeoffs.

Looking at your post and at your requirements (and after reading some of the comments), I would initially try to go with a self-balancing binary search tree, such as an [AVL Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) or a [Red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). These seem to be a good choice because you can easily make in-order traversals, and you get `O(log(n))` insertion, deletion and retrieval time.

Another alternative is to store hotels in a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), which is a data structure commonly used to implement a dictionary, and associate hotel names to whatever data you want.

I personally wouldn't go with a hash table if you want to sort data.

Comment: Why should I use a trie ?? my results are not linked, so I don't have nodes, all I have are keys and value the results are retrieved from a XML file. what about a dictionnary ?

Comment: @bouraxwebmaster Tries are not for "linked" data. Tries are used to store keys and (possibly) associate them with some data. Think of it as a dictionary implementation. You can think of nodes as hops within the letters of a hotel name.

Comment: I didn't try tries befor but thank you for the advice anyway. will try and check something new at least :)

Comment: @bouraxwebmaster Go ahead. The wikipedia article is very complete, I think it's a good start